# Phaser 3 - Sprite linear interpolation using movement queue

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework, linear-interpolation

I'm currently using Phaser 3 to represent my server's state.

Every x amount of time, I am sent the server's game state, this is what the client looks like:

```
var t1 = Date.now();
var serverUpdateDelta = 0;
Client.socket.on('usersPool', usersPool => {
  // usersPool is an object containing all the user data of sockets connected on the server. Looks something like this:
  /*
    usersPool = {
      "user1234": { x: 0, y: 0, direction: "right", moving: true },
      "testuser": { x: 200, y: 250, direction: "down", moving: false }
    }
  */
  // keeping count of milliseconds between updates (usually around 500m)
  serverUpdateDelta = Date.now() - t1;

  // for every user connected on the server...
  for(id in usersPool) {
    let data = usersPool[id]; // this is the user's data

    if(/* the player exists as a sprite in the game...*/) {
      // THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC SHOULD HAPPEN
    } else {
      genSprite(player);
    }
  }
});
```

The player's data contains a `movementQueue`, which is just an array of coordinates the user has been at. It might look a little like this:

```
[
  { x: 0, y: 0, direction: 'down', moving: false },
  { x: 5, y: 0, direction: 'right', moving: true },
  { x: 6, y: 0, direction: 'right', moving: false }
]
```

This is calculated on the server, but each `movementStack` (item in the movementQueue`) is generated every 25 milliseconds or so on the server.

The job now is, when receiving this movementQueue, to interpolate the values and move the sprite accordingly...

## Attempt 1

I first tried making a function which would interpolate once the update was received, like so:

```
// THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC SHOULD HAPPEN

// user's state on the client is set to an interpolated version of the one on the server
player.movementQueue = buffer(data.movementQueue);
```

The buffer will simply generate an interpolated array based on the serverUpdateDelta and game.loop.actualFps

then, in the Game.update function I ran the following:

```
for(id in spawnedPlayers) {
  // this will remove the first movementStack from the queue and returns in
  movementStack = spawnedPlayers[id].movementQueue.shift();
  // we then take this movementStack and update the user to that position (and play the walking animation)
  spawnedPlayers[id].update(movementStack);
}
```

So every game loop, we would remove a stack from the queue and set the user to it.

**This did NOT work. The game loop seemed to run Way more times than there were frames in the queue, making the player look like they were moving a small distance very slowly...***:

```
player.movementQueue = player.movementQueue.concat(buffer(data.movementQueue));
```

But then something weird happened, where the game loop could not keep up with the movementQueue and the player would move extremely slowly...

## Attempt 2

I then tried using tweens which would be really easy to implement, simply run:

```
// THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC SHOULD HAPPEN
_this.tweens.timeline({
    targets: player.sprite,
    tweens: data.movementQueue, // [{x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}]
    duration: serverDeltaTime/movementQueue.length, // duration between each tween in ms
  });
```

This worked ALMOST perfectly, except for one small detail:

Before, we would run a method for the player on each movementStack: `player.update(movementStack)`, this method would take the direction of the user and animate the sprite accordingly. Now we have no way of doing this...

SO

What methods or techniques could I use? What am I missing? What could I implement? I ask this because I'm stuck at this point.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Curious if you ended up finding a good solution?